# the order of function calls in c# (overloaded methods)

Tags: c#, generics, overloading, function-call

Why is the second function called here first and not the first. And how does the choice of functions occur in such situations?

```cs
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    var a = new A<char>();
    Use(a);
  }

  static void Use(IEnumerable<char> e) { 
    foreach (var _ in e) ;
    Console.WriteLine("Use(IEnumerable<char>)");
  }

  static void Use<T>(T e) where T : IEnumerable<char> { 
    foreach (var _ in e) ;
    Console.WriteLine("Use<T>(T) where T : IEnumerable<char>");
  }


  static void Use<T>(A<char> e) { 
    foreach (var _ in e) ;
    Console.WriteLine("Use<T>(A<char>)");
  }
}

class A<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the C# compiler follows *very* complex rules for overloading. See [section 12.6.4 of the C# v7 standard](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/expressions.md#1264-overload-resolution) for the painstaking details.

In this particular case, the compiler chooses the generic method instead of the non-generic method because it means the parameter is an *exact* match for the argument, which is deemed to be a "better conversion". It's a little bit like this:

```cs
void M(object o) { ... }
void M(string s) { ... }
...
M("test"); // Calls M(string)
```

The second method is a "better" function here because the conversion from `string` to `string` is "better" than the conversion from `string` to `object`.

In your case, it's a conversion from `A<char>` to `A<char>`, vs a conversion from `A<char>` to `IEnumerable<char>`.

As for why the second method is called rather than the *third* method - your third method is generic, but `T` can't be inferred via type inference, so it's not an *applicable function member*. If you change it to be a non-generic method (`static void Use(A<char> e)`), then that will be the best function member, because one of the tie-breaking rules is that a non-generic method is "better" than a generic method.